# Removing all Physics from a Node in Spritekit Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to remove all physics from a node, so that it has no physical proporties at all. I want it to act how it would act if I had just added the node without attaching a physics body. I have tried using the `.dynamic` property and I have found that this makes it so that no force can be applied to that node, but other nodes can still colide with it.

Basicly what I am trying to do is remove the physics body from a node.

I am uising spritekit and swift, thank you in advance.

Comment: Can't you set the physics body to nil?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume you have a node called 'character' that's set up like this.

```
    self.character.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: firstFrame, size: characterSize)
    self.character.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    self.character.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    self.character.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
```

You can change node's physicsBody to this:

```
    self.character.physicsBody = nil
```

All the above mentioned physics will be removed. You can also just change one or two attributes of the `physicsBody` like you said in your question. For example, you can change the collision category to prevent objects from colliding if this is what you want for your situation.

```
    self.character.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = colliderType.None.rawValue
```

If you try this make sure you have a 'none' category set up. This can be done like so.

```
    enum colliderType:UInt32 {
        case Character = 1
        case Block = 2
        case Wave = 3
        case None = 4
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did was this: I changed the categoryBitMask of the character to 0:

```
self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = 0;
```

This did the trick and after doing this, my character would not register any contact.